Multi-state survival analysis
I'm wondering if my use case fits this problem. I have a bunch of retail consumers, and I want to model the interval between their purchases. Because its' an online platform, we can observe other behaviours as well, such as browsing, viewing offers, etc... in between their purchases. A consumer can make a purchase multiple times, and we can not observe when they stop being a consumer entirely. A possible state transition graph is below, basically you can transition from one state to another, and maybe itself, if one state repeats after the other.

I'm thinking of modelling this a multi-state survival analysis problem, with possible events being making a purchase, browsing, viewing offers,... with no definite death event. Since the different events can happen multiple time as well, this is also a recurrent problem. Is this a suitable approach, and would it be able to model the difference sequence of events, or would I have to incorporate auto features into it? Any related reading resources on this problem would also be appreciated.
